# Can I use a property from a higher level field as input parameter for a lower level field in a GraphQL query?

Tags: graphql

Can I use a property from a higher level field as input parameter for a lower level field in a GraphQL query?

For example, a soccer club has players and seasons. In each season, a subset of the club's players play games for the club. The players of the club can have a different squad number each season.

I want to query the club's players for a season, along with their squad number for that season, and for each player I want a list of the games they have played in that season.

I can get a list of all the games (in all seasons) a player has played for the club. But I want to filter that list so only the games in the queried season are included in the list.

```
query {
  club {
    players {
      fullName
    }
    seasons {
      id <-- I want to use this value as input parameter $seasonId below
      players {
        edges {
          squadNumber
          node {
            fullName
            games(seasonId: $seasonId) { <-- how to use the value here?
              homeTeam
              awayTeam
            }
          }
        }
      }
      games {
        players {
          edges {
            goalsCount
            node {
              fullName
              games(seasonId: $seasonId) { <-- how to use the value here?
                homeTeam
                awayTeam
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If this is not possible, should I introduce a `SeasonPlayer` GraphQL type (containing the squad number of the player for a season)? Or should I use a query parameter containing the season ID?